# React invalid event onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem calling a function on an img in reactjs:

this is my components:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';
import logo from '../../files/logo.png';
import './index.css'
import pedra from '../../files/pedra.png';
import papel from '../../files/papel.png';
import tesoura from '../../files/tesoura.png';

export default function Joken() {
    // useEffect(()=>{

    // },[]);
    var jogadorEscolha = 0;
    var jogadorPoontuacao = 0;
    var computadorPoontuacao = 0;
    var computadorEscolha = 0;
    var ganhador = -1;
    var nomeJogador;


    function jogar(escolha){
        jogadorEscolha = escolha;

        computadorEscolha = Math.floor((Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1))) + 1;

    if((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    }

    else if((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-1").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-2").classList.remove('selecionado');   
    document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-3").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computador-escolha-1").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computador-escolha-2").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computador-escolha-3").classList.remove('selecionado');



    document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-" + jogadorEscolha).classList.add('selecionado');

    document.getElementById("computador-escolha-" + computadorEscolha).classList.add('selecionado');


    if(ganhador == 0) {
    document.getElementById('containerx').innerHTML = 'Empate';
    }
    else if(ganhador == 1) {
    document.getElementById('containerx').innerHTML = 'Jogador Ganhou';
        jogadorPoontuacao++;
    }
    else if(ganhador == 2) {
    document.getElementById('containerx').innerHTML = 'Computador Ganhou';
        computadorPoontuacao++;
    }

    document.getElementById('jogador-pontos').innerHTML = jogadorPoontuacao;

    document.getElementById('computador-pontos').innerHTML = computadorPoontuacao;

    }

    return (

        <div className="containerxd">
        <div className="containerDates">
            <div className="JogadorUm"><h2>{localStorage.getItem('user')}</h2></div>
            <div className="PlacarX"><h2>Placar:</h2><span id="jogador-pontos">0</span></div>
            <div className="JogadorDois"><h2>Computador</h2></div>

            </div>
            <div className="containerSpot1">
            <div className="jogador" id="jogador">
                <ul id="jogador-escolha"> 
                    <li><a id="jogador-escolha-1" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={pedra} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="jogador-escolha-2" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={papel} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="jogador-escolha-3" onClick={jogar(1)}><img src={tesoura} alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="versus">vs</div>
            <div className="computador" id="computador">
                <ul id="computador-escolha">
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-1" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={pedra} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-2" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={papel} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-3" onClick={jogar(1)}><img src={tesoura} alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="containerx">

        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am getting this error:

> index.js:1375 Warning: Invalid event handler property `onclick`. Did
>   you mean `onClick`?

I don't know why or how to declare the function correctly because it's not going to my function, I'm grateful if anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error said you should use `onClick` instead of `onclick`

```
<div className="computador" id="computador">
                <ul id="computador-escolha">
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-1" onclick={() => jogar(1)}> <img src={pedra} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-2" onclick={() => jogar(2)}> <img src={papel} alt="" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="computador-escolha-3" onclick={() => jogar(3)}><img src={tesoura} alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

And you can't call your `jogar()` method into a string you must give to `onClick` event a function like this `onClick={() => jogar(2)}`

Comment: hello thanks bro u can help me? Now i got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null on this line: document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-1").classList.remove('selecionado');

Comment: and this is my css selecionado ul#jogador-escolha li a:hover, ul#jogador-escolha li a.selecionado, ul#computador-escolha li a.selecionado{ opacity: 1; }

Comment: You probably doesn't have an element if the id `jogador-escolha-1`

Comment: i have : <li><a id="jogador-escolha-1" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={pedra} alt="" /> </a></li>

Comment: Did you edit your onClick event like I said ? `onClick={() => jogar(1)}`

Comment: yess Yes is working the problem is in this code snippet

Comment: As I said you did not edit your onClick correctly. Please update like this : `onClick={() => jogar(1)}`

Comment: omg 
omg I did not think it interfered, can you explain me why?

Comment: Of course if you simply write `onClick={jogar(1)}` it calls directly your function even if you did not click. But if you give a function to onClick event like this `onClick={() =>  jogar(1)}` it calls your function only when you click on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, you should be using `onClick`. Unlike normal HTML, JSX props are case-sensitive, so `onclick` is different from `onClick` -- and the click event calls `onClick`.

Comment: hello thanks bro u can help me? Now i got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null on this line: document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-1").classList.remove('selecionado');

Comment: and this is my css selecionado ul#jogador-escolha li a:hover, ul#jogador-escolha li a.selecionado, ul#computador-escolha li a.selecionado{ opacity: 1; }

Comment: That means there's no element with the ID "jogador-escholha-1" in your page. Probably because it hasn't been rendered yet by the time you're trying to access it. Rather than using getElementById, you should be using React refs to refer to DOM elements. Look into refs and how to use them, and if you still can't get it working with refs, open a new question about that with your new ref-using code.

Comment: u can give me one example please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear about what's wrong - there's no such a thing as `onclick` in React, you should replace it with `onClick`.

---

#### Second case

If you won't wrap you function in curly braces `{}`, it will not be called, but will be parsed as a `string`.

---

#### Third case

You will probably get `stack exceeded error`, since you are invoking the function immediately.

```
onClick={() => jogar(1)}
```

Comment: hello thanks bro u can help me? Now i got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null on this line:  document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-1").classList.remove('selecionado');

Comment: and this is my  css selecionado ul#jogador-escolha li a:hover, ul#jogador-escolha li a.selecionado, ul#computador-escolha li a.selecionado{
  opacity: 1;

 }

Comment: @gabriel That element doesn't exist. `document.getElementById("jogador-escolha-1").` is undefined.

Comment: @usuário amável  i have <li><a id="jogador-escolha-1" onClick={jogar(1)}> <img src={pedra} alt="" /> </a></li>